# Never ending while() loop

Tags: php, session, while-loop

I need to add a while loop for my script. It's a while $points < 17 ( draw_cards)

Maybe you can guess, it's a cards game. I wish it was as simple as that because it won't work. It gets stuck in an endless while loop.

```
if(FORM_stand("Stand")){
   while ($total_dealer < 17){
     list_dealer_hand();
     draw_dealer_card();
   }
}
```

If i run my script it goes on forever. Showing me for example `7, 7, 3, 7, 3, 9, 7, 3, 9, 2, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 5, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 5, Queen, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 5, Queen, Jack, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 5, Queen, Jack, King, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 5, Queen, Jack, King, 4, 7, 3, 9, 2, 6, 10, Ace, 5, Queen, Jack, King, 4, 8,`

before eventually repeating 
`Notice: Undefined index`

But i if i were to use:

```
if(FORM_stand("Stand")){
   list_dealer_hand();
      if ($total_dealer < 17){
         draw_dealer_card();
      }
}
```

I need to press `Stand` manually a couple of times because it's an `if` but this way it will keep drawing cards untill his points are 17 or higher, meaning the `If` works but the `While` never ends.

I don't know if you need any more information, in case you do, please ask away. Since i've been stuck on this while loop for 2 days now. And no one seems to be able to help me.

Thanks in advance!

PS: If i run the while loop and press control + f5 after all the errors are shown, it shows me this: `3, 10, 7, 9, 6, King, 8, Queen, Jack, 4, 2, Ace, 5, ,` and in the point section: `85
Busted!`

I know all points together are 95, but since i used a case for my Ace that if points are > 11 it will count as a 1 instead of an 11. Mabye this bit will help you!

list_dealer_hand()

```
function list_dealer_hand() {
foreach($_SESSION["dealer_hand"] as $dealer_card=>$points) {
    echo $dealer_card;
    echo ', ';
}
}
```

and draw_dealer_card()

```
function draw_dealer_card() {
    $dealer_card = array_rand($_SESSION["dealer_pile"]);
    $_SESSION["dealer_hand"][$dealer_card] = $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$dealer_card];
    unset($_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$dealer_card]);
```

}

My case system for points looks as follows:

```
$total_dealer = 0;
$text_dealer = '';
foreach($_SESSION["dealer_hand"] as $dealer_card=>$dealer_points) {
switch($dealer_card)
{
    case "King":
    case "Queen":
    case "Jack":
    case "10":
    $total_dealer += 10;
    break;
    case "Ace":
    if($total_dealer >= 11)
        {
        $total_dealer += 1;
        }else{
            $total_dealer += 11;
        }
        break;
    case "9":
        $total_dealer += 9;
        break;
    case "8":
        $total_dealer += 8;
        break;
    case "7":
        $total_dealer += 7;
        break;
    case "6":
        $total_dealer += 6;
        break;
    case "5":
        $total_dealer += 5;
        break;
    case "4":
        $total_dealer += 4;
        break;
    case "3":
        $total_dealer += 3;
        break;
    case "2":
        $total_dealer += 2;
        break;
}
}
```

EDIT: Session dealer_pile

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["dealer_pile"])) $_SESSION["dealer_pile"] = array(
2           =>  2,
3           =>  3,
4           =>  4,
5           =>  5,
6           =>  6,
7           =>  7,
8           =>  8,
9           =>  9,
10          =>  10,
'Jack'      =>  10,
'Queen'     =>  10,
'King'      =>  10,
'Ace'       =>  11 );
```

Comment: your value never greater than 17 thats why check your value it is increment or not

Comment: increment `$total_dealer ` in while loop

Comment: was `$total_dealer` value changing in `list_dealer_hand();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`draw_dealer_card()` needs to increase `$total_dealer;` otherwise the loop will go an forever.

## A more elaborate answer

You only calculate the total once and never again in the while loop, that is why the dealers total will never increase and therefore will never be greater than 17.

Put the code that converts a card to its value in its own function, so you can use it anywhere

```
<?php
/**
 * return the value of the card for the current total
 * @param string $card the card to convert to count
 * @param int $current_total the current total of the player/dealer
 * @return int the value of $card
 */
function get_card_value($card, $current_total) {
    switch($card) {
        case "King":
        case "Queen":
        case "Jack":
            return 10;

        case "Ace":
           return ($current_total > 10) ? 1 : 11;

        case "10":
        case "9":
        case "8":
        case "7":
        case "6":
        case "5":
        case "4":
        case "3":
        case "2":
            return (int) $card;
    }
    return 0; // this should not happen probably abort here
}
```

From here it is easy, edit your while loop like this:

```
<?php
while ($total_dealer < 17){
    list_dealer_hand();
    draw_dealer_card();
    /* this is bad code using end(), 
     * which might not always get the last drawn card.
     * Also calculation of total is wrong this way:
     *   What happens if dealer draws Ace, Ace, Ace, King? 
     *   Should be 1+1+1+10 = 13 but will result in 11+1+1+10=23
     */
    $total_dealer += get_card_value(end($_SESSION['dealer_hand']), $total_dealer);
}
```

## Correct calculation of total

To make your code more robust add a function `calc_total(array $cards)` which calculates the total of an array of cards and use it instead in the while loop to recalculate the dealers total. A function like this could look like this

```
<?php
function calc_total(array $cards) {
    //this is a little tricky since aces must be counted last
    $total = 0;
    $aces = array();
    foreach($cards as $card) {
        if($card === 'Ace') {
            $aces[] = $card;
            continue; // next $card
        }
        $total += get_card_value($card, $total);
    }
    // add aces values
    if (($total + 10 + count($aces)) > 21) {
        //all aces must count 1 or 21 will be exceeded
        return $total + count($aces);
    }
    foreach($aces as $card) {
        $total += get_card_value($card, $total);
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Now your while loop could lool like this

```
<?php
while ($total_dealer < 17){
    list_dealer_hand();
    draw_dealer_card();
    // recalculate the dealers total
    $total_dealer = calc_total($_SESSION['dealer_hand']);
}
```

## Setting up the pile

Mixing of number and string keys is perfectly valid php, but also most of the time misleading. In your pile you  only need the cards, the values are not imoprtant, you can get a cards value at all time by calling `get_card_value($card, 0)`. So set up the pile like this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["dealer_pile"])) $_SESSION["dealer_pile"] = array(
    'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2'
);
```

Also change the draw_dealer_card function

```
<?php
function draw_dealer_card() {
    //get a key
    $key = array_rand($_SESSION["dealer_pile"]);
    // add the card to the hand
    $_SESSION["dealer_hand"][] = $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$key];
    /* 
     * why are you removing it from pile, the pile might 
     * contain multiple cards of each type
     */
    // unset($_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$dealer_card]);
}
```

Notice how the `$_SESSION['dealer_hand']` is no longer associative. Take this into account whenever you are adding cards to it, just use, `$_SESSION["dealer_hand"][] = $the_new_card`

Comment: I appreciate the effort you take into helping me, but it doesn't seem to work =/, if i add only the first 2 pieces. The advanced case system and the while. It won't add a value if i press start game. Which gives the dealer 1 card. And secondly if i press stand then, say he got a 3 at the beginning it will show me these cards after i press stand: `3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2,` with a points total of: `17`

Comment: And if i add your cal_total function it says there is an unexpected { at line `if (($total + 10 + count($aces) > 21) {` , edit: nevermind you just used 2 ( at the beginning where only 1 was needed.

Comment: Thanks @Farewyth the code checking hinted me to incorrect syntax, but i didn't see it, should have used an IDE instead of writing it directly here :) - Also I only repeated code absolutly needed to be repeated. It is not complete everywhere, e.g. the `while` will still go into the `if(FORM_stand("Stand")){` block. Just ask if you need further help.

Comment: the calc_total can be called anytime right? To calculate the dealer's hand?

Comment: And for some reason it counts the Ace as 0 all the time. No matter when the dealers gets it in his hand, form start or from stand

Comment: I fixed the problem of not counting the dealers card at the start, all that remains is the Aces problem, it counts them as 0 all the time.

Comment: Please supply the structure of `$_SESSION['dealer_pile']` and `$_SESSION['dealer_hand']`

Comment: Added the dealer pile session

Comment: You should not mix number and string keys, php allows it but it will result in unwanted results most of the time, when adding arrays with + operator, or using array_merge, or array_unique, since you have string keys make them all strings, like `array( '2' => 2, '3' => 3, ..., 'Ace' => 11);
This might not be the reason calc_total fails, but change that first.
EDIT: Also in `draw_dealer_card` just collect the keys, like .. hold on I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah i read something about that it might give problems later on using  2,3,4 and 'Queen', 'King' for example. Thanks for pointing this out again, i changed it right away!

Comment: Thanks again by the way! I accepted your answer since it did everything i asked for!

Answer (score 2):

Your current code gets static value of `$total_dealer` and checks in while loop without incrementing, which results in infinite loop.So try putting foreach{} loop inside while loop, which will allow `$total_dealer` to increment value after each selection.

```
if(FORM_stand("Stand")){
$total_dealer = 0;
   while ($total_dealer < 17){
     list_dealer_hand();
     draw_dealer_card();

$text_dealer = '';
foreach($_SESSION["dealer_hand"] as $dealer_card=>$dealer_points) {
switch($dealer_card)
{
    case "King":
    case "Queen":
    case "Jack":
    case "10":
    $total_dealer += 10;
    break;
    case "Ace":
    if($total_dealer >= 11)
        {
        $total_dealer += 1;
        }else{
            $total_dealer += 11;
        }
        break;
    case "9":
        $total_dealer += 9;
        break;
    case "8":
        $total_dealer += 8;
        break;
    case "7":
        $total_dealer += 7;
        break;
    case "6":
        $total_dealer += 6;
        break;
    case "5":
        $total_dealer += 5;
        break;
    case "4":
        $total_dealer += 4;
        break;
    case "3":
        $total_dealer += 3;
        break;
    case "2":
        $total_dealer += 2;
        break;
}
}
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think total_dealer is supposed to increment by 1 I think it's supposed to add the previous drawn card to its total.

Comment: You have  point, but untill Farewyth specifies more about the problem we can give answers based on wild guess only

Comment: Sorry, Yes but @WBOCo. was right, it needs to add with the points worth of the cards. And not with 1.

Comment: @Farewyth from where do you get `points worth of the cards` ?

Comment: Please say my assumptions was correct.You was getting the value of `$total_dealer` from switch statement and then calling the while loop. ?

Comment: @krishna Yes this is correct. I have switch with all the values. And beneath that I have the while loop.

Comment: so in while loop `$total_dealer` is not incremented which makes `$total_dealer` never > 17 if $_SESSION["dealer_hand"] has cards to total value < 17

Comment: @krishna yeah, everyone has pointed this out, however i don't really know what to increment it with.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try putting whole `foreach($_SESSION["dealer_hand"] as $dealer_card=>$dealer_points) { ` inside while loop

Comment: check my edited answer. i have applied the mentioned solution.Please check was this applying with your code ?

Comment: @krishna It seems to have worked a little bit, but the score and and list_dealer_hand() are a bit messed up. At least it isnt repeating forever

Comment: @krishna for example, i hit start game, the dealer gets delt a 2. I click stand. And the dealer cards are this: `2, 2, King,` and his points are: `34
Busted!`

Comment: try giving a default case with adding 0 to `$total_dealer`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$total_dealer=0;
    if(FORM_stand("Stand")){
       while ($total_dealer < 17){
         list_dealer_hand();
         draw_dealer_card();
         $total_dealer =$total_dealer+1;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think total_dealer is supposed to increment by 1 I think it's supposed to add the previous drawn card to its total.